# While Iterating through ArrayList using for loop instead of Iterator, why does the output reference an address instead of actual object?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created a list from objects from my user defined class called students.

```
class Student {
    String name, phone, group;

    Student(String name, String phone, String group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

And accessed it in the following way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("Ayush", "9841293412", "L1N1");
        Student s2 = new Student("Rahul", "9842432423", "L1M1");
        Student s3 = new Student("Gaurav", "984129231", "L1N2");

ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
    al.add(s1);
    al.add(s2);
    al.add(s3);
    al.add(s4);
    al.add(s5); 

   for(Student name:al){
       System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
```

But the output is referencing object like following:

```
Name: Student@1baf61
Name: Student@b5272
```

I don't know why this has happened.

Comment: You have to override `toString` method in order to determine how a `Student` object is represented as a String.

Comment: Name returned in the loop is a student object and not its name. Put a getter for name field or override toString() to a more readable form

Comment: I've created a getter for name with String return type but it still says cannot find symbol. And I didnot get where to override toString()

Answer (score 3):

Just extract the name field instead:

```
class Student {
    String name, phone, group;

    Student(String name, String phone, String group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", group='" + group + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student("Ayush", "9841293412", "L1N1");
        Student s2 = new Student("Rahul", "9842432423", "L1M1");
        Student s3 = new Student("Gaurav", "984129231", "L1N2");

        ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);
        al.add(s3);

        for (Student name : al) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + name.name);
            System.out.println("Name: " + name.getName()); // Using a getter
            System.out.println(name); // Using toString
        }
    }
}
```

As a best practice use a getter or a toString implementation to better represent your model

Comment: This worked thanks. Also could you please explain about toString implementation a  bit in detail.

Comment: System.out.println invokes the toString method of the passed object and thats how to got the output. Please accept the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString method in your StudentClass or if u want only the name you can implement a getter method in your StundentClass..

```
class Student {
    String name, phone, group;

    Student(String name, String phone, String group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", group='" + group + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

**usage toString**

```
for(Student name:al){
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
}
```

**output:**

> Name: Student{name='Ayush', phone='9841293412', group='L1N1'}
>
> Name: Student{name='Rahul', phone='9842432423', group='L1M1'}
>
> Name: Student{name='Gaurav', phone='984129231', group='L1N2'}

**usage of your getter**

```
for(Student name:al){
    System.out.println("Name: " + name.getName());
}
```

**output:**

> Name: Ayush
>
> Name: Rahul
>
> Name: Gaurav